# Trying to change SQL statement to use EXISTS instead of IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, exists

I was reading (and am still learning) about the difference between the `EXISTS` and `IN` operators in SQL. Is it possible to change the following statement so it uses an `EXISTS` rather than `IN`? I've tried but the query is taking a very long time to complete. So I'm obviously doing something wrong.

In the below example would it be more efficient to use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`? There would be no more than 10 OperationRecordID records returned from the current sub-query used for the `IN` statement.

```
SELECT SPAS.SessionRecordID,
       ( SELECT MIN(TimeValue) AS MinAnaes
           FROM tblTMActualTimes TMAT
          WHERE OperationRecordID IN
                 ( SELECT OperationRecordID
                     FROM tblTMActualOperation TMAO
                    WHERE TMAO.SessionRecordID = SPAS.SessionRecordID
                 )
            AND CFTimeDefinitionID = 'INTOANS'
       ) AS FirstAnaesthetic
  FROM tblSPActualSession SPAS
```

Comment: Which DBMS (Oracle/PostgreSQL/MySQL/SQL Server/...) are you using?

Comment: Having thought about this again, instead of using the IN sub-query I could perform a JOIN in the original sub-query instead. Though I'm curious which is considered best practice/most efficient.

Comment: SQL is a declarative language, the query optimizer is free to rewrite `in` to `exists` or the other way round.  Which is more efficient depends on a lot of things (database, statistics, indexes) but not on the way you phrase the question in SQL.

Comment: I am using MSSQL Server 2005.

Comment: In the abstract, I think `EXISTS` probably makes more logical sense for this case than either `IN` or `JOIN`. But you're asking about efficiency -- you even use the phrase "best practice/most efficient" as though that's one thing -- and that will most likely depend on the DBMS you're using, and on the specific version of the DBMS. On MySQL, for example, I think that `IN` and `EXISTS` will both be much slower than a `JOIN`, because it doesn't have good optimizations for correlated `IN`/`EXISTS` subqueries (though that may have changed in versions newer than when I last looked at it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments it depends on the data what is more suitable for the situation. But if you what to do it in an exist you can do it something like this:

```
SELECT 
    SPAS.SessionRecordID,
    ( 
        SELECT 
            MIN(TimeValue) AS MinAnaes
        FROM tblTMActualTimes TMAT
        WHERE EXISTS
                 ( 
                    SELECT 
                        NULL
                    FROM 
                        tblTMActualOperation TMAO
                    WHERE 
                        TMAO.SessionRecordID = SPAS.SessionRecordID
                        AND TMAT.OperationRecordID=TMAO.OperationRecordID
                 )
            AND CFTimeDefinitionID = 'INTOANS'
       ) AS FirstAnaesthetic
  FROM 
    tblSPActualSession SPAS
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I was missing "AND TMAT.OperationRecordID=TMAO.OperationRecordID" when I tried it earlier. Will test it out tomorrow.